# На разных платформах selenium python работает по разному

Tags: python, selenium

Я написал код, для авторизации на некотором сайте. Я произвожу поиск и ввод текста этим кодом:

```
            user = "user"
            driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(user)
            password = "password"
            driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
```

И в случае с windows все прекрасно работает. При переходе на debian 10 выдает ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Версию chromedriver и сам chrome везде поставил актуальную.
Заранее спасибо за советы

Comment: Попробуйте поставить/обновить пакеты Selenium WebDriver на Debian.

Comment: У вас по запросу id возвращается словарь, выведите в консоль и посмотрите, что в нем